# Unable to register achievements

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, achievements

I've been unable to register any achievements.  I keep getting the following:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#3502) Object at achievement URL is not of type game.achievement","type":"OAuthException","code":3502}}
```

When I run my URL through the linter, I get:

```
Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed

Inferred Property:  The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

Although when I load the URL myself I clearly see those set in the meta tags.  My HTML looks like:

```
<html>
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# game: http://ogp.me/ns/game#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id"      content="<MY_APP_ID>" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"        content="game.achievement" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"         content="http://<MY_DOMAIN>/ach10.html" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"       content="Title" /> 
  <meta property="og:description" content="Description" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"       content="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" />
</head>
<body>
Hmm..
</body>
</html>
```

Also interesting, is the graph API sees it as:

```
{
   "url": "http://<MY_DOMAIN>/ach10.html",
   "type": "website",
   "title": "http://<MY_DOMAIN>/ach10.html",
   "updated_time": "2012-03-09T19:49:14+0000",
   "id": "<ID>"
}
```

And the scraped URL returns nothing ... anyone have any ideas?  I've also tried adding the Game Achievement object in the Open Graph settings and every combination of Sandbox Mode/Social Discovery enabled and disabled.

Comment: See if Facebook's crawler is definitely seeing what you think it is:
`curl -A "facebookexternalhit/1.1" -i $URL_GOES_HERE` works for me - most common causes for problems like this are a redirect based on browser detection or login or an og:url tag pointing to another address

Comment: @Igy, I gave that a shot and I'm seeing the file just as expected.  Comes back with a 200 and all the meta tags set.  Very frustrating problem.

Answer (score 1):

you have to include game:points meta tag to complete your game.achievement